# How to make text below another text in a Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

1.I'm creating a login page, I want to "Forget Password" text below the "sign up " text what should I do? I also want to add a process bar below the "Forget Password" Text

2.Here is the XML code for my login layout: I was trying to put process bar and Forget Password text in the liner layout, but these two items will not be shown in the login page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    tools:context=".LoginPage">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-27dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgcard"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="40dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
            android:text="Welcome Back!"
            android:textColor="#0F0F0F"
            android:textSize="34dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
            android:text="This here add detail about article."
            android:textColor="#3A3A3A"
            android:textSize="18dp" />


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputUsername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_editext"
            android:hint="User Name"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_editext"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:paddingLeft="18dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_book"
                android:text="you don't have account already?"
                android:textColor="#363636"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/register"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_book"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textColor="#1F1F1F"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resetText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Forgot Password"

                />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have put the forgot password and progress bar inside the inner Linnear layout which is horizontal. This makes them end up outside of the screen.

Moving them to the outer Linear layout should fix your problem.

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-27dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bgcard"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="40dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_bold"
        android:text="Welcome Back!"
        android:textColor="#0F0F0F"
        android:textSize="34dp" />

   <!-- Your other views here -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_book"
            android:text="you don't have account already?"
            android:textColor="#363636"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_book"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="#1F1F1F"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resetText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Forgot Password" />

    <ProgressBar
       android:id="@+id/progressBar"
       style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`

Comment: Also you need to change forgot Password android:gravity="center" to android:layout_gravity="end"

Answer (score 0):

Because you have several items in a linearlayout with horizontal orientation that do not fit.

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="you don't have account already?"
                android:textColor="#363636"
                android:textSize="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/register"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:text="Sign Up"
                android:textColor="#1F1F1F"
                android:textSize="16dp" />



        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resetText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Forgot Password"
            />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Jetpack Compose

```
Column {
        Text("you don't have account already?")
        Text("Sign Up")
        Text("Forgot Password")
}
```